# Should top-cow-universe be aliased with witchblade?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should top-cow-universe be aliased with witchblade tag?

Or am I the only person in the universe who's a fan of Witchblade from TV series and only randomly accidentally stumbled on the fact that there's a separate comic universe containing it?

Answer (score 2):

I enjoyed the Witchblade TV series, but never read any of the comics.  I say nay to making this alias.

Comment: +1 for having the same opinion, -1 for liking the Witchblade TV series. :P

Comment: @IanPugsley Hey, I was like 13 when it aired.  Give young-me a break!

Comment: @IanPugsley - -1 for not liking anything with Yancy Butler

Comment: @DVK please, everyone loves Hard Target!

Answer (score 2):

As a big time reader of all things Top Cow, I don't think so.  While Witchblade is part of the Top Cow universe, much of the Top Cow universe is unrelated to Witchblade (or, not typically related).

An analogy; imagine [top-cow-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-cow-universe) is [x-men](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men) (or even [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics)), and [witchblade](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/witchblade) is [wolverine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolverine).